# Scheme: The object () is not applicable

Tags: scheme, lisp

It's a beginner question. However it's more than 2 hours that I'm trying to find out the error (I've also made searches) but without success.

```
(define a (lambda (l i) (
    (cond ((null? l) l)
          (else (cons (cons (car l) i) (a (cdr l) i))))
)))
```

The function `a` should pair the atom `i` with each item of `l`. For example:

`(a '(1 2 3) 4)` should return `((1 4) (2 4) (3 4))`

However when I try to use invoke the function I get:

```
The object () is not applicable
```

**What's the error in my function?**

I am using `mit-scheme --load a.lisp` to load the file. Then I invoke the function a by typing in interactive mode.

Comment: check out [the search facility at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+object+%28%29+is+not+applicable+%5Bscheme%5D+is%3Aq). It finds 26 questions (including this one) with the same exact wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error, as usually happens in lisp languages, depends on the wrong use of the parentheses, in this case the extra parentheses that enclose the body of the function.

Remove it and the function should work:

```
(define a (lambda (l i) 
            (cond ((null? l) l)
                  (else (cons (cons (car l) i) (a (cdr l) i))))))
```

Rember that in lisp parentheses are not a way of enclosing expressions, but are an important part of the syntax: `((+ 2 3))` is completely different from `(+ 2 3)`. The latter expression means: sum the value of the numbers 2 and 3 and return the result. The former means: sum the value of the numbers 2 and 3, get the result (the number 5), and call it as a function with zero parameters. This obviously will cause an error since 5 is not a function...

Comment: Thank you very much!! I know that but I would have never noticed that I added those extra parenthesis. I was concerned with the `l` returned by the cond and I was sure that the rest was correct. Thanks again

Comment: @collimarco Using an editor that takes care of indentation for you will help in detecting lots of unbalances.